# can't sent sms from android 4.4.4 nexus 5

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

hi i have my code a button when pressed it will send a sms to a number it works with my android 4.4.2 but not in nexus 5 4.4.4 heres my code i don't know what I'm doing wrong:

```
smsus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.i("Send SMS", "");

                    Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    smsIntent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:"));
                    smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");

                    smsIntent.putExtra("address", phonenumber);
                    smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", messageToSend);
                    try {
                        startActivity(smsIntent);

                        Log.i("Finished sending SMS...", "");
                    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                "SMS failed, please try again later.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }
            });
```

thank you.

Comment: Do you have logcat output from the Nexus 5?

Comment: i don't see any error

Comment: In Logcat (check all modes) or on the device?

Comment: yes nothing :( i don't know what else

Answer (score -1):

change

Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

to

Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);

and delete  the below line

smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");

See if it works.